# How do you do an `UPDATE ... FROM ...` query in jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

e.g. a query like the below

```sql
UPDATE some_table
SET some_table.foo = other_table.bar
FROM other_table
WHERE some_table.id = other_table.id
```

I already looked at [the documentation for the update statement in jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/update-statement/) but could not find an example using a `FROM ...` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is indeed missing from the manual. [I've created a bug report for this](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7908). However, it is available from the API and documented in the Javadoc. Just add the `FROM` clause where you'd expect it to be: In [`UpdateFromStep.from()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdateFromStep.html#from-org.jooq.TableLike-)

```java
ctx.update(SOME_TABLE)
   .set(SOME_TABLE.FOO, OTHER_TABLE.BAR)
   .from(OTHER_TABLE)
   .where(SOME_TABLE.ID.eq(OTHER_TABLE.ID))
   .execute();
```